# Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку менялся фон?

Tags: javascript, html

Хочу создать кнопку, чтоб при нажатии на нее менялся фон страницы?

Comment: Спасибо к репутации не плюсуется. ;)

Answer (score 5):

Если нужно рамдомизировать выбор цвета, то можно сделать так.

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function() {
    var button = document.getElementById('input_button_bg_change');
    var body = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0];
    var colors = ['blue', 'grey', 'black', 'white', 'red', 'green', '#aaa', '#FFAACC', 'rgb(122,111,110)'];
    button.onclick = function() {
        body.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)];
    };
};
</script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="input_button_bg_change" value="Change background color"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.body.style.background = '#f00';" />
```

**Добавлено.**

И через функцию:

```
onclick='switchBg();'

var bgar = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f'], curBg = 0;
function switchBg(){ 
    document.body.style.background = bgar[++curBg % bgar.length];
}
```

Comment: А как сделать так чтоб при новом нажатии на него появлялся другой фон, например: синий, красный, желтый, и.т.д.

Comment: Тогда через функцию: `onclick='switchBg();'`. И функция: `var bgar = ['#f00', '#0f0', '#00f'], curBg = 0;function switchBg(){document.body.style.background = bgar[++curBg % bgar.length];}`

Answer (score 2):

Код не проверял на работоспособность

```
<script>
var colorArray = [ "#000", "#fff", "#eee" ]; // массив с цветами
var i = 0; // итератор

function changeColor(){
    document.body.style.background = colorArray[i]; 
    i++;
    if( i > colorArray.length - 1){
        i = 0;
    }
}

</script>
<input type="button" onclick="javascript:changeColor();"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head> </head>
  <body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://scriptjava.net/source/scriptjava/scriptjava.js"></script>

    <div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="bg_set('#ffffff');">белый фон</div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="bg_set('#ff0000');">красный фон</div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="bg_set('http://bablogon.net/img/0081z.png');">картинка на фоне</div>
    <div style="cursor:pointer;" onclick="bg_rem();">Вернуть по умолчанию</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      var bg_ini = function () {
        if($$c.get('bg_style')!=undefined) {
          if($$c.get('bg_style').indexOf('#')===0) {
            $$($$().body,'background',$$c.get('bg_style'));
          }
          else {
            $$($$().body,'backgroundImage','url('+$$c.get('bg_style')+')');
          }
        }
        else {
          //фон по умолчанию
          $$($$().body,'background','#55ff55');
        }
      }

      var bg_set = function (value) {
        $$c.set('bg_style', value, 60*60*24*30);
        bg_ini();
      }

      var bg_rem = function () {
        $$c.erase('bg_style');
        bg_ini();
      }

      $$r(function () {
        bg_ini();
      });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

http://learn.javascript.ru/play/Y11Wp